# Show AdMob ad on surface view

Tags: java, android, admob

I just started writing my first Android game and now I also want to try out AdMob. But I cant get it to show ads...
I followed this tutorial to create the game: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html
It uses a canvas to draw everything.

This is the important code I guess:

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
Graphics graphics;
Audio audio;
Input input;
FileIO fileIO;
Screen screen;
WakeLock wakeLock;

AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int frameBufferWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int frameBufferHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
            frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

    float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
            / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
            / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
    graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
    audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
    screen = getInitScreen();
    //setContentView(renderView);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyGame");

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    adView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(adView);

    View gameView =renderView;
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(adView);
}

private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-number/number");

    adView.setId(12345);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    return adView;
}


private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
Use "Ads" as a filter in logcat.
You need to use a test device like this:

```
private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("your ID")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Further more I changed the adUnitId to the one given here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
And then I changed the order in which the Views get added (it seemed like the gameView was overlaying the adView):

```
    View gameView =renderView;
    layout.addView(gameView);

    adView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(adView);
```

With these changes it worked.

Comment: Share the logcat... Ad erros can be filtered by "Ads"

Comment: Thanks for the filter hint, with that i could get it to work. I will add the changes i made in the first post.